# opencv2/intensity_transform.hpp: No such file or directory

Tags: opencv, cmake

I'm quite a noob using cmake and compilers, I have compiled opencv-4.4.0 with contrib on my desktop, while facing the issue `opencv2/intensity_transform.hpp: No such file or directory` when I'm trying to include such file using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/intensity_transform.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
```

The opencv is installed to default `/usr/local` directory, so opencv2 could be found in `/usr/local/include/` directory. Only `intensity_transform` failed, with error message:

```
Scanning dependencies of target srobot
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/srobot.dir/img_aug_OPENCV/image_enhance_by_opencv.cpp.o
${ROOD_DIR}/src/img_aug_OPENCV/image_enhance_by_opencv.cpp:4:10: fatal error: opencv2/intensity_transform.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2/intensity_transform.hpp>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
src/CMakeFiles/srobot.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/srobot.dir/img_aug_OPENCV/image_enhance_by_opencv.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/srobot.dir/img_aug_OPENCV/image_enhance_by_opencv.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:85: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/srobot.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/srobot.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
# CMakeLists from src directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
add_definitions(-DUSE_OPENCV)

# using mkl/cuda
set(MKL_DIR /opt/intel/mkl)
set(CUDA_DIR /usr/local/cuda)

include_directories(${MKL_DIR}/include ${CUDA_DIR}/include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${MKL_DIR}/lib/intel64 ${CUDA_DIR}/lib64)


# this command recursively add *.cpp files in src and add them to list: srcs
file(GLOB_RECURSE srcs ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/img_aug_OPENCV/image_enhance_by_opencv.cpp)
message(STATUS "PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: " ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
message(STATUS "srcs: " ${srcs})
add_library(srobot SHARED ${srcs})


set(OPENCV_LIBS opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs)
target_link_libraries(srobot mkl_core ${OPENCV_LIBS})
```

Actually I'm facing this with original opencv-3.5.4, it is also installed from source. Here is the cmake commands I used:

```
cmake \
    -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
    -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
    -D ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF\
    -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
    -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/ubuntu/Installation/opencv_contrib-4.4.0/modules/ \
    -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf2/bin/python \
    -D BUILD_TIFF=ON ..
```

And system info:

- Ubuntu 18.04;
- CUDA 10.0.0;

I will provide more sys info if necessary. Is this related to platform? It seems that source code was from Windows platform. Help needed!

Comment: Please, provide(add to the question post) the **complete** error message. It should include, among other things, the location of the `#include` directive. Or even a stack of these directives.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Sorry, message updated!

Comment: Oh, so it is **your code** which you want to build. It is `CMakeLists.txt` file which responsible for add appropriate include directories and libraries. Please, show that file.

Comment: @Tsyvarev done! Damn, I thought it would be easier...